# Pull tab content from anywhere of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code creates tabs, but I have issues displaying the content of the tab.

How can I rewrite the JS to be able to pull the tab-content from anywhere of my page?

```js
const btn = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('button'))
btn.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    btn.forEach((item) => {
      item.classList.remove('active')
    })
    item.classList.add('active')
    document.getElementById('tab').setAttribute('data-tab', index)
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button> Tab 1</button>
  <button> Tab 2</button>
  <button> Tab 3</button>
  <div id="tab" class="tabs inliner">
    <div>
      <h2> CONTENT HAST TO BE HERE </h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2> OR HERE </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since I'm using WordPress shortcodes, they don't get executed.
I have to place them somewhere else and then display them wherever the tabs are as tabcontent.

Recreating only the `<div id="tab" class="tabs inliner">` while rest stays in place is not working either.

Any ideas?

As i stated, tried to replicate the specific  but did not work.

Comment: Calling [`document.querySelectorAll('button')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) will provide a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) result that has a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method. No need to convert it to an array if you go that route instead.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.

I got the code from codepen and did not understand a thing.

Could you explain for a noob?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the active tab content, you will have to grab the value of the button that was clicked and locate the corresponding tab content.

```js
const
  wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper'),
  btnArr = wrapper.querySelectorAll('button'),
  tabWrapper = wrapper.querySelector('.tabs'),
  tabArr = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.tab');

const setTab = (index) => {
  tabArr.forEach((tab, tabIndex) => {
    const isActive = tabIndex === index;
    tab.classList.toggle('active', isActive);
    btnArr[tabIndex].classList.toggle('active', isActive);
  });
  tabWrapper.setAttribute('data-tab', index);
}

const onTab = ({ target: { value } }) => setTab(value - 1);

btnArr.forEach((btn) => btn.addEventListener('click', onTab));

setTab(0); // Set initial state to tab #1
```

```css
.tab { display: none; }
.tab.active { display: block; }
button.active { background: #FFD; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button type="button" value="1">Tab 1</button>
  <button type="button" value="2">Tab 2</button>
  <button type="button" value="3">Tab 3</button>
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab">
      <h2>Tab 1 Content</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <h2>Tab 2 Content</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <h2>Tab 3 Content</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const btn = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('button'))
btn.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    btn.forEach((item) => {
      item.classList.remove('active')
    })
    item.classList.add('active')
    document.getElementById('tab').setAttribute('data-tab', index)
    //Change the content of the First H2 Element
    //Step 1 Select The HTML Element tha
    let FirstH2Element = document.querySelector('h2');
    //Step 2 : Change the FirstH2Element Text
    FirstH2Element.textContent = item.textContent // the tap content

  })
})
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button> Tab 1</button>
  <button> Tab 2</button>
  <button> Tab 3</button>
  <div id="tab" class="tabs inliner">
    <div>
      <h2> CONTENT HAST TO BE HERE </h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2> OR HERE </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```